# "No Bootable Device" after installing Ubuntu

Tags: live-usb

I was installing ubuntu and when the installation completed, the installer told me to restart my laptop (acer).

Then  it showed me "No bootable Device " error.

What should I do now ?
Thanks

Comment: Welcome, which version of Ubuntu?

Comment: have you tried `boot-repair`?

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 Lts

Comment: Acer (maybe all models) normally needs UEFI update & if SSD, SSD firmware update. And then you set Secure Boot, and password and enable "trust" on the Ubuntu entry in UEFI. Either reset password or never loose it or you convert system to brick. Some now require ctrl-s  in UEFI to open settings. https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2297947&p=13369742#post13369742 Acer Aspire E15 will not dual boot, many details Trust settings in step 35
http://askubuntu.com/questions/627416/acer-aspire-e15-will-not-dual-boot